# emacs better syntax highlighting for js

Tags: javascript, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I'm a long time vim user looking to make the switch to emacs ... my vim kung fu is quite good but I suspect with emacs I can code even faster.

So far the Javascript syntax highlighting is inferior though. I've looked at https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode which says to install version 27, then install the package ... but that did nothing.

I'll post the different versions below. Am I missing something ?

Vim:
[image: vim coloration]

Emacs:
[image: emacs coloration]

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same font-locking for the object properties as the function calls, as shown in your vim example, you can <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-face` `js2-object-property` to inherit from `font-lock-variable-name-face`, or add an entry to `custom-set-faces` in your init

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; ...
 '(js2-object-property ((t (:inherit font-lock-variable-name-face)))))
```

As you aren't getting any highlighting for function calls currently, it looks like you probably need to <kbd>M-x</kbd>`package-reinstall` js2-mode first.